# Intuitive way to find the minimum surface in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: geometry, optimization

Suppose we have two arbitrary closed curves which intersect neither each other nor themselves. By intuition, I guess that the minimum surface ending at boundaries is unique and it is achieved by this method:

take an arbitrary point on one of the curves and find the minimum distance between that point and the entire of the other curve. And do this method for all points so you have made the minimum surface.

a. Is this evaluation correct? and if so,

b. How about two curves that their normal vectors are perpendicular? And, how about if one chosen point has more than one point 'image' on the other curve to make the distance minimum?

Comment: Your intuition is not correct. The problem of minimum surfaces is very hard.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface